# Converting specific letters to lowercase in Java

Tags: java, lowercase

Suppose I have a String in java with the value "hELLo".

How do I convert it into "heLLo" (The second character must be lowercase) ?

Comment: What is the *specific* rule? What have you tried?

Comment: I haven't tried anything since I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Given the information you've provided, simple assignment would be sufficient: `s = "heLLo";`

Comment: So only uppercase E to lowercase e? `x = x.replace('E', 'e');`

Comment: plus 1 for honesty,straight as an arrow  "haven't tried anything"

Comment: What if the string is unknown, but the second character of the string must be in lowercase?

Comment: Then that's a different problem than you've mentioned so far, and would have a different solution.

Comment: So it's the second character now? You could have mentioned that.

Comment: @azurefrog so whats the solution for that then

Comment: Why don't you figure out what you actually want to know, then [edit] your question to ask that?  So far you've asked three different questions, two of which aren't even *in* your question, but only in the comments.

Answer (score 2):

There are lot more other ways, but best would be to have a good read at few [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/853017/convert-single-char-in-string-to-lower-case) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375649/converting-to-upper-and-lower-case-in-java).

As simple as that, use [java.lang.String#replace](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replace%28char%2Cchar%29)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "hELLo";
        String modified = original.replaceFirst("E" , "e");
        System.out.println(modified);
    }
```

**output**

```
heLLo
```

You can also use [replaceAll](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%29), for replacing all occurrences of letter.

**Edit - Replace 2nd char always**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "hELLo";
        char secondChar = original.charAt(1);
        String modified = original.replaceFirst(String.valueOf(secondChar) , String.valueOf(secondChar).toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(modified);
    }
```

**output**

```
heLLo
```

**Using String substring**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String original = "hELLo";
        String secondChar = original.substring(1,2);
        String modified = original.replaceFirst(secondChar , secondChar.toLowerCase());
        System.out.println(modified);
    }
```

Comment: What if all the characters in the word are unknown, but the second character must always be converted into lower case?

Comment: @Falcon2908 As per OP question, i think  scope is very very wide, you can think of n number of cases, but to get him started, we  should give him some pointers, He can come back and ask few more questions.

Comment: @ankur-singhal Falcon2908 is the OP

Comment: @ScaryWombat got it, :)

Comment: @Falcon2908 done as per your need, apologies for misunderstanding

Comment: Your substring version would convert ALL occurrences of the uppercase second char to lowercase NOT just the second char.

Comment: @ScaryWombat corrected

Comment: @Falcon2908 pls accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "hELLo";
    String str1 = str.replace("E","e");
```

use replace() of String class

Answer (score -2):

String str = "hELLo";
        String str1 = str.replace("E","e");

use replace() of String class

Comment: It is a comment, please explain it further more otherwise your answer will be closed under **not an answer** tag.